# 3D bar graph display hides front bars from certain angles

Tags: matplotlib, graph

Not sure if this is a glitch, but how do I make the perspective of the bars behind correct? Right now from different angles, some of the front bars are hidden/glitchy/look weird. Pics attached.
[This looks weird:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJSqN.png)
[This looks weird:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rob4I.png)
[This looks fine but not from the angle I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztvj8.png)

I've tried changing the order in which things are graphed.

Comment: This is my first post, so I didn't realize my attached pics came as links, but if you click on the "This looks weird:" and "This looks fine but not from the angle I want" the images should show up